# Save Config Button Not work in payment methods

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, configuration, sales, save

> I was trying to add a new payment method klarna. I configured klarna
>   in a proper way and I couldn't save it.
>
> Further try to some other changes in
>   stores->setting->configuration->sales->payement method  But nothing
>   gets saved.
>
> It takes me to the top of the page. Can anyone say why it occurs like
>   this and need a solution for it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I saw that **Authorize.Net** was turned **`on`** by default, but `not configured`.

So I turned **`off`** **Authorize.Net** and then made changes in the payement method and so the save config worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case Firefox was auto-filling the "PayPal Express Checkout" configuration with Magento login credentials. Click "Configure" next to "PayPal Express Checkout" and remove the auto-filled credentials.

Answer (score 1):

i have also faced this issue. its not a js error or anything. if you have saved your login credentials in your browser means, its automatically storing in paypal cofig. i just removed the configs. its working[image: working solution]

Answer (score 0):

There may be two cause to not work save button.

1. May be there is a required field, due to that save button is not working. So first check all accordion and make sure no required field is blank.
2. Please check in console, may be due to some JS error, save button is not working.

Comment: If there is required field it takes scrolls down to the the place where the field is required and not to the top @Dj_Dev

Comment: I have checked it in console and I find nothing wrong in that.